# SwiftUI: Edit list row relement with swipe action and present modal sheet

Tags: swift, xcode, list, swiftui

Hi. I have a swiftui project with a list. I would now like to add 2 trailing swipe actions to this list, once the .onDelete and a edit swipe action to the left of it.
Like this:
[Look:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wABLZ.png)

To achieve this in swiftui I added the following code to my list:

```
            List {
                
                ForEach(timers, id: \.id) { timer in
                                        
                    TimerRow(timer: timer)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { IndexSet in deleteTimer(IndexSet) })
                .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: false) {
                    
                    Button {
                        // Open edit sheet
                        isShowEditTimer.toggle()
                        
                    } label: {
                        
                        Image(systemName: "pencil.circle")
                    }
                }
            }
```

But unfortunately only the edit function is displayed now:

[Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySlip.png)

Do you know how I can solve my problem?

But now to my real problem:
I now want to open a modal sheet when the edit swipe action of a line is pressed. But how do I find out which line was swiped on? With the .onDelete function we get an IndexSet, but nothing here. I would also like to give the struct that is called in my sheet this certain swiped element (CoreData object):

```
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowEditTimer) {
            EditTimerView(timerObject: ???)
        }
```

By the way, this sheet is applied to my navigation view.

I would be really happy if someone could help me and if you didn't report my post. Maybe this question has been asked somewhere deep in StackOverflow, but I'm also relatively new to swiftui (always UIKit before) and don't understand every stackoverflow post yet.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Eric and welcome to SO! If you wanna get answers to your question pls read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Anyway, I faced the same problem that you describing and if you don't mind I will show how to solve it on my code base

```
import SwiftUI

struct Car: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    var model: String
}

class CarViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cars: [Car] = [
        .init(model: "Audi"),
        .init(model: "BMW"),
        .init(model: "Chevrolet"),
        .init(model: "Honda"),
        .init(model: "Toyota")
    ]
    
    func del(_ car: Car) {
        if let deletingCarIndex = self.cars.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == car.id}) {
            self.cars.remove(at: deletingCarIndex)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm = CarViewModel()
    @State var editingCar: Car?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(vm.cars) { car in
                Text(car.model)
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                        Button(role: .destructive) { // if you implement custom swipeAction you have no more access to .onDelete
                            vm.del(car) // if you stay in ForEach loop you have access to car instance and can find index of this instance in array
                        } label: {
                            Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                        }
                        Button {
                            edit(car)
                        } label: {
                            Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil.circle")
                        }
                    }
            }
            .sheet(item: $editingCar) {
                reset()
            } content: { car in
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text(car.model)
                    Text(car.id)
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    func reset() {
        editingCar = nil
    }
    
    func edit(_ car: Car) {
        editingCar = car
    }
}
```

Hope now it clear for you

Comment: If you want to edit element in a `.sheet` this post might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72697262/pass-optional-state-to-non-optional-binding-view-variable