# SwiftUI: Opening sheet with binding to new array element fails

Tags: ios, swiftui, indexoutofboundsexception

While learning SwiftUI, I'm building a simple iOS app with a model that contains an array of items. These items can be created and edited.

The main view lists the items and a `+` button for creating a new item. Tapping an item opens another view for editing the item in a sheet. This happens through the binding `editItem`, which is a `@State` to make it mutable (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72697928/883073)).

The problem arises when I try to open the edit view for an item right after its creation: The code fails on runtime (iPhone 14 Pro simulator) when creating a new item:

```
Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:600: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

I've boiled down the app to the following minimal example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Model {
    var items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: String
}

struct MainView: View {
    @Binding var model: Model
    @State private var editItem: Binding<Item>?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List($model.items) { $item in
                ItemCardView(item: $item.wrappedValue)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        editItem = $item
                    }
            }
            Button(action: {
                model.items.append(Item(id: "New item"))
                editItem = $model.items.last // WORKS WITHOUT THIS
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }
        }.sheet(item: $editItem) { $item in
            let _=print($item)
            ItemEditView(item: $item)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemCardView: View {
    var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.id)
    }
}

struct ItemEditView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    @State private var editingItem: Item = Item(id: "dummy")
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Title", text: $editingItem.id)
        .onAppear {
            editingItem = item
        }
        .onDisappear {
            item = editingItem
        }
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State var model = Model(items: [])
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView(model: $model)
        }
    }
}
```

The app works without the line

```swift
editItem = $model.items.last // WORKS WITHOUT THIS
```

If this line is removed, the `+` button will create a new item that you can edit by tapping it.

I've not been able to pinpoint the failure in the debugger as the exception isn't triggered in my code: The binding passed into `ItemEditView` looks fine when printing it (it prints it twice though, I don't know if that's a hint).

I would be interested both in understanding why my approach doesn't work, but also suggestions of better ways of solving the underlying problem.

I'm using XCode 14.3 on an M1 laptop and targeting iOS 16.4.

Comment: You should only use `@State` inside a View, you should look into `@StateObject` and `ObservableObject` because that might be more suitable here. Or declare `model` as a `@State` object instead of a binding inside the `MainView`

Comment: Moving `model` to `MainView` indeed makes it work - thanks! To be clear you mean that using `@State` in `MyApp` is wrong but making it a `@StateObject`/`ObservableObject` and keeping it in `MyApp` could be fine?

Comment: Yes and it might alos be more appropriate depending depending on what it's supposed to be used for.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson They actually do use `@State` in `ScrumdingerApp` in Apple's own tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/passing-data-with-bindings#Pass-a-binding-into-the-list-view

Comment: And the `@State` docs say that it may be used in `App`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state

Comment: State should always be private what is the point of a State of type Binding? Binding by definition is a source of truth and Binding is a two-way connection. You can access the State’s  Binding with $

Comment: @loremipsum Updated snippet to make state private. It's a `Binding` in order to be able to edit it in `ItemEditView` and it's a `State` because it's mutable in that it may bind different (or no) items at different times. I do use `$` to create the binding in`$model.items.last`. It's based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72697262/pass-optional-state-to-non-optional-binding-view-variable/72697928#72697928.

Comment: I made a comment about that there,  there is no documented use of a Binding as a literal type only as a property wrapper, seems a bit like duct tape to me.

Comment: Technically `$editItem` is a `Binding` of a `Binding`. Type `let someVar = $editItem` somewhere in the `body` then open the "Quick Help" or "Circle with Question Mark" on the right side of Xcode (Inspectors), then click on `someVar`;  it more than likely says `Binding<Binding<Item>?>` for the type which is not `@Binding var item: Item` as per your `ItemEditView`.

Comment: @loremipsum You're correct that the type of `$editItem` is `Binding<Binding<Item>?>`. This makes sense to me as the "outer" `Binding` controls whether or not to open the sheet and the "inner" `Binding` allows us to edit the actual data in the model. While it may be odd to have state of binding, I still don't understand why it shouldn't work nor what an appropriate solution would be? I created the full minimal project at https://github.com/bisgardo/swiftui-binding-issue that you're more than welcome to play with.

Comment: I think I’ve already said all I can on the subject the only difference in between now and 2 months ago is the use of struct as Data Models, Apple always recommended the use of reference types for Data Models and at WWDC they reiterated their stance with the new Observable Macro. I would “fix” this by using reference types for Data and Value types for managing UI.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store a binding in a state. Bindings are a pair of get and set closures that need to be recreated the same as the View structs, so you'll need:

```
@State private var editItem: Item?

editItem = model.items.last
```

Then you can make a new binding in your sheet that looks up the same item in the model.

Comment: 1. It's not a typo because `editItem` has type `Binding<Item>?` and the `$` is what creates a binding for that value. Omitting it causes a type error.
2. I'm not sure I understand: Doesn't accessing `$item` without the closure access the state? How can it avoid that? Adding the capture (with or without `$`) yields a compiler warning that the capture is unused. And it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I didn’t notice `editItem` has the wrong type, should be `Item`

Comment: Think I figured out the problem, you shouldn't store bindings in state.

Comment: I don't see how I can edit the item without it being passed as a binding? I created the full minimal project at https://github.com/bisgardo/swiftui-binding-issue and would greatly appreciate if you could show your solution in that project (sorry for the long delay).

Answer (score -1):

It all brings down to the difference between what a @State, @StateObject are. SwiftUI’s State property wrapper is designed for simple data that is local to the current view but it’s not designed to share between views, so is used only within the view and it should be also initialised within it. It’s supposed to store simple data (value type basically as Apple claims). StateObject  on the other hand we use for reference type source of truth -  so can be passed as reference and is not copied.
Potential solution would be:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var model = Model()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView(model: model)
        }
    }
}


class Model: ObservableObject {
    var items: [Item] = []
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State var model: Model
    @State var editItem: Binding<Item>?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List($model.items) { $item in
                ItemCardView(item: $item.wrappedValue)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        editItem = $item
                    }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                model.items.append(Item(id: UUID(), title: "New item"))
                editItem = $model.items.last
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
            }.frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        }.sheet(item: $editItem) { item in
            ItemEditView(item: item)
        }
    }
}
```

References:

- [`State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state)
- [`ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject)

Comment: Binding should be used as a property wrapper per documentation. Also State should always be private per the link you provided.

Comment: @loremipsum can you please elaborate on what you mean by "Binding should be used as a property wrapper per documentation"?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding

Comment: The documentation says that Binding is a “property wrapper”. It is a bit of an oxymoron to make a State a literal Binding type becuase by definition State is a source of truth and Binding is a two way connection. There is no documented use for Binding as a literal type.